# Making dynamically created dropdowns match value in Vue model from initial dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dynamic, html-select

I have a dropdown that gets populated from an array in my Vue model, like so:

```
<!-- First dropdown -->
<select v-model="building">
  <option v-for="building in buildings" v-bind:value="building.id">
      {{ building.name }}
  </option>
</select>
<!-- Entries Input -->
<input v-model="entries" type="number">
```

After the user selects this dropdown and clicks a button, a bunch of other dropdowns will be created (the amount depends on the number the user typed in another input field):

```
<!-- Dynamically created dropdowns -->
<div v-for="entry in entries">
  <select>
    <option v-for="building in buildings" :selected="building.id == building">
      {{ building.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I need the dynamically created dropdowns to have the same selection as the first dropdown. I can't bind them via v-model because I need each of them to be able to be changed without affecting the other ones.

Any idea how to do this? I thought my code `:selected="building.id == building"` would work but it does not seem to.

Comment: You're using `building` for a data item and also for a v-for alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind your second dropdown to a computed property based on the first one as follows :

```
 computed:{
          cpt_building:{
                    get(){
                      return this.building;
                      },
                    set(value){
                     //use your value whatever you want
                      }
                }
```

template :

```
  <div v-for="entry in entries">
     <select v-model="cpt_building">
       <option v-for="build in buildings" :selected="build.id == building">
         {{ building.name }}
       </option>
     </select>
   </div>
```

or you could create another data property and changing it by watching the first one.

```
   data(){
        return{
           building:0,
           building2:0,
           ...
            }
          },
    watch:{
         building(val){
              this.building2=val;
               }
           }
```

template :

```
  <div v-for="entry in entries">
     <select v-model="building2">
       <option v-for="build in buildings" :selected="build.id == building">
         {{ building.name }}
       </option>
     </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is a helpful start. However, wouldn't all of the dropdowns then be bound to `cpt_building`, so if one of them changed then they all would?

Comment: the second select depends on the first one and the first one doesn't

Comment: This is the correct answer, I'm just trying to understand why it works. I'll read up on computed properties now then. Thanks.